# Displaying Loading Image using CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class, responsive-images

I currently have the following CSS code that I apply to a `div` element that displays a responsive image.

```css
.my-img-container {
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    background: url("https://lorempixel.com/300/160/") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
  }
  >img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-img-container">
  <img srcset="https://lorempixel.com/540/304 540w, https://lorempixel.com/960/540 960w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 540px, 100vw" src="https://lorempixel.com/300/160">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is have an image display in the background while the responsive image is loading, hence the `content` in the CSS, but it's not working. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the spinner as a background to the image:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif) no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<img srcset="https://picsum.photos/540/304 540w, https://picsum.photos/960/540 960w" sizes="(min-width: 576px) 540px, 100vw" src="https://picsum.photos/300/160">
```

Comment: it will be weird when we using `object-fit: contain`

Answer (score 14):

Instead of loading a smaller image to show as a *loader*, simply rotate a pseudo element instead.

It has the benefit of being able to start much faster than an image and  save an extra server call.

```css
.my-img-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
.my-img-container:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-color: transparent red transparent red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loader 1s linear infinite;
}
.my-img-container > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300">
</div>
```